# using groovy binding along with groovyclassloader

Tags: java, groovy

I was reading http://www.slideshare.net/glaforge/going-to-mars-with-groovy-domainspecific-languages/46-How_to_inject_the_direction for doing something similar on a code base we inherited recently. The problem is that the code we inherited use groovy from java application and uses GroovyClassLoader to load and then instantiate/invoke groovy script. I was wondering, if there is any way to use groovy bindings with the approach of groovyclassloader. Or is there a more appropriate way? (expando meta class?)

Answer (score 0):

GroovyClassLoader create classes overriding `groovy.lang.Script`.

On the class Script, you have a setBinding method which is the same Binding as in your presentation. Call `setBinding()` before calling `run()`

Comment: The code does the following. 1) Creates a new class using groovy classloader. 2) Make an instance using Class.newInstance and 3) execute the method using instance.invokeMethod. When I cast the instance to Script, I get a classcast exception.

Comment: Post your code and an example of a file you load, but if you don't load a script, you can't use a Binding

Comment: The groovy code itself is generated using some pretty complex string operation. The templates that generate the code seems to indicate that one is "class XXX { .....}" and the other is "class YYY extends XXX {....}".  The whole string is then passed to groovyclassloader.parseClass(). So, look like as suspected, Binding cannot be used. Is there an alternate solution?

Comment: The purpose of a `Binding` is to inject into a script a "context" (default properties or methods). If you are generating your classes, you can't use a Binding, but you don't need it : generate the stub you need with your template

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The code that generates the classes are very general purpose stuff. I was wondering if we can use HandleMetaClass to inject a per-instance meta class and add a property. Do you know if there are performance or concurrency issues with that?